# Bitcoin core cli importdescriptors (miniscript)

Tags: bitcoin-cli, output-script-descriptors, miniscript

I created a miniscript descriptor and wanted to see how it looked like in core(testnet).
So i ran:

```
importdescriptors "[{"desc": "wsh(or_d(pk([658b6bd9/44'/1'/0'/0]tpubDEpdABTw4YQ1W4oMMompKvpFJZ7odXW8k1htPD58fUgpXnGEruJjaCe8qeQYBzF9Vd1ChXBXdqFSRcj6QgJsJc7jtTysihbQiUbKVsCSgXS/<0;1>/),and_v(v:pk([31e0f720/44'/1'/0'/0]tpubDEZqwGLJHbE6PtGCcGQir3s45XqePxCAmaS3eADQ5XCTweNQQ6vbpj6WDfqzcgxRV3UbChTtU468ATwP51rVYWs28pRT7mFrtvrG8UmWbev/<0;1>/),older(6))))#8yc7zwgd", "range": [0, 999], "timestamp": 1686487688, "internal": false, "watchonly": true, "active": true}]"
```

Then i got error:

```
[{ "success": false, "error": { "code": -5, "message": "A function is needed within P2WSH"}}]
```

How should i correct the command?
(sorry for the codes here in a mess)